How to port this delete mark and buffer function from harpoon to harpoon2
I got this function that works in harpoon:
        function()
          local index = require("harpoon.mark").get_current_index()
          if index ~= nil then
            local config = require('harpoon').get_mark_config()
            table.remove(config.marks, index)
            local global_settings = require("harpoon").get_global_settings()
            if global_settings.tabline then
              vim.cmd("redrawt")
            end
          end
          require("mini.bufremove").delete(0, true)
        end,

This function removes harpoon mark and also deletes buffer using mini.bufremove.

      local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }
      local harpoon = require("harpoon")
      local list = harpoon:list()

      -- Based on https://github.com/ThePrimeagen/harpoon/blob/0378a6c428a0bed6a2781d459d7943843f374bce/lua/harpoon/list.lua#L184
      function Remove(item)
        item = item or list.config.create_list_item(list.config)
        print("Hello")
        local Extensions = require("harpoon.extensions")
        local Logger = require("harpoon.logger")

        local items = list.items
        if item ~= nil then
          for i = 1, list._length do
            local v = items[i]
            print(vim.inspect(v))
            if list.config.equals(v, item) then
              -- this clears list somehow
              -- items[i] = nil
              table.remove(items, i)
              list._length = list._length - 1

              Logger:log("HarpoonList:remove", { item = item, index = i })

              Extensions.extensions:emit(
                Extensions.event_names.REMOVE,
                { list = list, item = item, idx = i }
              )
              break
            end
          end
        end
      end

Then you can use this function with mini.bufremove.
